# How to upload a file in WCF along with identifying credentials?

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, wcf-security, wcf-streaming

I've got an issue with WCF, streaming, and security that isn't the biggest deal but I wanted to get people's thoughts on how I could get around it.

I need to allow clients to upload files to a server, and I'm allowing this by using the transferMode="StreamedRequest" feature of the BasicHttpBinding.  When they upload a file, I'd like to transactionally place this file in the file system and update the database with the metadata for the file (I'm actually using Sql Server 2008's FILESTREAM data type, that natively supports this).  I'm using WCF Windows Authentication and delegating the Kerberos credentials to SQL Server for all my database authentication.

The problem is that, as the exception I get helpfully notes, "HTTP request streaming cannot be used in conjunction with HTTP authentication."  So, for my upload file service, I can't pass the Windows authentication token along with my message call.  Even if I weren't using SQL Server logins, I wouldn't even be able to identify my calling client by their Windows credentials.

I've worked around this temporarily by leaving the upload method unsecured, and having it dump the file to a temporary store and return a locator GUID.  The client then makes a second call to a secure, non-streaming service, passing the GUID, which uploads the file from the temporary store to the database using Windows authentication.

Obviously, this isn't ideal.  From a performance point of view, I'm doing an extra read/write to the disk.  From a scalability point of view, there's (in principle, with a load balancer) no guarantee that I hit the same server with the two subsequent calls, meaning that the temporary file store needs to be on a shared location, meaning not a scalable design.

Can anybody think of a better way to deal with this situation?  Like I said, it's not the biggest deal, since a) I really *don't* need to scale this thing out much, there aren't too many users, and b) it's not like these uploads/downloads are getting called a lot.  But still, I'd like to know if I'm missing an obvious solution here.

Thanks,
Daniel